# WooCommerce price filter showing products with higher price than selected

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have used the default WooCommerce price filter widget in my sidebar. When I use that widget to filter products using price, the filtered results also include some products with the higher price than selected.

Say, I have selected the price range from 500 to 3000, then when filtered, the results show me the products having price of 3500, 4800 etc.

What can be the issue? can anyone help me to get this fixed?

Comment: How many products are available in your listing?

Comment: There are currently more than 380 products